# Python parser - defining output filenames

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, saxparser

A beginner's question - I have a Python SAX parser that extracts lines of text from a .xml file and writes them to a .txt file. Now I want it to run against all files in the directory and derive the output filename from the input filename, but I can't get this to work.

The parser itself works fine so in the code below I've just shown the blocks where the input and output files are specified. Any suggestions for a simple way of doing this?

```
# Code begins

import sys
import re
from enum import Enum

sys.stdout = open("outputab123.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8")

import xml.sax

# ~ 50 lines of SAX parser code

# Final block of code
   parser.parse("ab123.xml")
   sys.stdout.close()
```

For each output .txt file, I simply want to take the name of the input .xml file and put "output" in front.

Comment: Are you parsing all files in a directory recursively?

Comment: Yes, or I want to at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the input filename, split it to get the part before the period, and then prepend/append "output" and ".txt":

```
xmlfile = "ab123.xml"
txtfile = "output" + xmlfile.split(".")[0] + ".txt"
print(txtfile)
```

Output:

```
outputab123.txt
```

So overall, your code could look something like:

```
listofiles = # define list of files here (eg. using glob)

for xmlfile in listoffiles:
    # parsing here
    parser.parse(xmlfile)
    sys.stdout.close()

    txtfile = "output" + xmlfile.split(".")[0] + ".txt"
    sys.stdout = open(txtfile, encoding="UTF-8")
    # write to text file here
```

To get a list of `.xml` files in a directory, you can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```
listoffiles = glob.glob("/path/to/directory/*.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks. Using that approach, where should I specify the input directory? I'm getting an error as below:                                                                                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mypath/parser.py", line 5, in <module>
    for xmlfile in listoffiles:
NameError: name 'listoffiles' is not defined

Comment: `listoffiles` should be defined before the `for` loop. Editing my answer.

Comment: Great stuff - thanks! I had to rework one line as `txtfile = xmlfile.split(".")[0] + "output.txt"` to stop it putting "output" at the beginning of the filepath, and with that change it does exactly what I wanted it to.